# Send Form Data to Controller (Codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a pop up menu and inside that I have a form and a text box. I want to retrieve that value and submit it to my controller. Once submitted I want my pop up to close and go back to the other page. I tried with AJAX but I might be doing something wrong.

```
<form onsubmit="return(testing());" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="vip_text_box" id="vip" value="<?php echo $total_amount ?>"> <br>
      <input type="submit" name="Redeem"  value="Redeem">
</form>
```

Now My Javascript

```
function testing() {
  $test = document.getElementById("vip").value;
  var url = base_url + '/index.php/home/redeeming_form_value';
    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url : url,
      data : {'myvalue':test},
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
    });
};
```

In my controller

```
function redeeming_form_value() {

     $amount = $this->input->post('myvalue');

     return $amount;
```

In the AJAQ I have a success, and want to alert my data(the value) to make sure it even works but it does nothing. When i click submit my pop up view just goes away.

Comment: Add `return false` at the very end of your `testing()` function. It will prevent form from submitting itself and reloading the page, cause it seems like your problem.

Comment: It kinda helped but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dataType: "json", to your Ajax

```
dataType: "json",
```

Then in your controller use json_encode to return your data

```
$arr = array('amount' => $amount);
return json_encode($arr);
```

Test the response in success

```
console.log(data.amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it..

HTML

```
<form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="vip_text_box" id="vip" value="<?php echo $total_amount ?>"> <br>
      <input type="submit" name="Redeem" id="submit"  value="Redeem">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
  var test = $("#vip").val();
  var base_url= 'http://localhost/shop';
  var url = base_url + '/index.php/home/redeeming_form_value';
    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url : url,
      data :'myvalue='+test,
      success: function(data){
         msg= eval(data);
         amount= msg.amount;
         alert(amount);
         }
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

At your Controller

```
function redeeming_form_value() 
{

     $amount = $this->input->post('myvalue');

     echo json_encode(array('amount'=>$amount));

}
```

Comment: It says cannot find variable test. when I changed it to $test still nothing

Comment: are you getting the value of test from form. check once then try hope it works.

Comment: and what is the value for base_url.

Comment: Its still nothing I dont even get alert and Its localhost .. Its used throughout this project i only changed the ending for my function

Comment: what is the value og base_url...where you set it?

Comment: `onsubmit="return(testing());"` change it to `onsubmit="testing()"`

Comment: Just tired it, still nothing

Comment: did you load jquery library in HTML page.

Comment: ya and still nothing